# Connect a microphone to a smart TV for karaoke purposes

Tags: android-tv

I recently bought a Smart TV (Philips 65OLED707/12) and I was wondering if I could connect one (or preferably two) microphones to it, to sing Karaoke with my family and friends.

I want to be able to mix the sound from the microphones and the sound of the karaoke app so that all is outputted by the TV speakers.

Are there microphones, or specific microphone stands capable of doing that? What should I look for in their specs?

It is Android 11.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download any Karaoke apps from the Play Store on your Android TV. Few of the best ones are listed below:

1. [Starmaker](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.starmakerinteractive.starmaker)
2. [Smule](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.smule.singandroid)
3. [Karaoke Anywhere](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.joltsoft.karaokeanywhere.robot)
4. [KaraFun](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.recisio.kfandroid&hl=en&gl=US) (has remote control)

For the mic part, Android TVs support Bluetooth mic input. You can either use a Bluetooth-enabled remote with voice input support (Google Assistant) **or** a dedicated karaoke Bluetooth mic for the matter.

Since it is Android 11 you should be able to connect more than one multi-point Bluetooth device. I can see that your TV is pretty high-end and has Bluetooth 5.0 ([specs](https://www.philips.co.uk/c-p/65OLED707_12/oled-7-series-4k-uhd-oled-android-tv)) which indeed supports multipoint connections.*

**Alternatively,** you can buy a karaoke set that combines the two mic inputs before sending it to the TV, which makes things super smooth (*recommended*) 
[Video for reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oJNiT4k9th0)

Few Bluetooth mics (Amazon,UK).. (shared links don't seem to work since I'm not from UK so I'm just adding the names)

1. MAONO Bluetooth Karaoke Microphone, MKP100 *(Recommended)*
2. ACESHOP Karaoke Wireless Microphone Portable Handheld
3. EKLEVOR Wireless Microphone, Karaoke Bluetooth Microphone

Comment: Thanks ! I found no bluetooth microphones (Except for these ugly handled-bluetooth-speaker-with-a-microphone), so I'll look at the video.

Comment: Ah. The first thing needed in the video is a dedicated sound bar. I feel I don't need one since the TV speaker feels okay to me, and it will be a high investment to buy a soundbar that matches the quality of the TV. Back to looking for bluetooth microphones, I think. If you have any brand name to suggest, I'll take it.

Comment: Suggesting products could be tricky because availability of it depends on where you live and also they can discontinue being sold so I shouldn't in fact. But anyway, from the specs website of Philips, I am guessing you live in UK. I'll add the links to the answer. Just a tip.. while searching for mics don't include "karaoke". I can totally agree they are pretty ugly

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really helped !